# Why is the quotient ring $\frac{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{R}} = \left \{ 0 \right \}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

As the question says, why is the quotient ring $\frac{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{R}} = \left \{ 0 \right \}$ ? Shouldn't it be $\mathbb{R}$? We have that $\frac{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{R}} = \left \{ x + \mathbb{R} \mid x \in \mathbb{R} \right \}$ and the sum of two real numbers is just another real number. And in a more general case, is $\frac{A}{A} = \left \{ 0 \right \}$ or $\frac{A}{A} = A $?

Comment: How many elements are in the set $\{x+\mathbb R:x\in\mathbb R\}$? Can you name *two*?

Comment: $2+\mathbb R$ is the same set as $3+\mathbb R$.  There is only one such set, not a separate one for each number.

Comment: 1 and 0 for instance. If we take $x=2$, we know that $-2 \in \mathbb{R}$ but $-1 \in \mathbb{R}$ too, so while we have that $2+(-2)=0$ we also have that $2+(-1)=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $x + \mathbb{R}$ is a set, not a number. As $x + r$ is a real number for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$ (as you've correctly said), the set $x + \mathbb{R}$ is just the set of all real numbers, $\mathbb{R}$ for *every* $x \in \mathbb{R}$. So $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{R} = \{\mathbb{R}\} \cong \{0\}$.

In the more general case, for a group $A$, the quotient group $A/A = \{x + A \mid x \in A\}$. But as $x + a \in A$ for every $x, a \in A$, again $x + A = A$ itself. So $A/A = \{A\} = \{0\}$.

Answer (score 5):

The quotient $A/B$ means "the elements of $A$ partitioned into equivalence classes where two elements $x,y \in A$ are equivalent if their difference is in $B$: $x \sim y \iff x-y \in B$."  Since every two real numbers in $A = \mathbb{R}$ differ by some element of $B = \mathbb{R}$, there is only one equivalence class.  Pick a representative of this very large equivalence class.  I like "$0$".

Since in addition, the quotient of a ring with one of its ideals, itself for instance, is a ring, we would like to pick the representative so that the result is obviously a ring.  Since every ring contains $0$ ...

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer, using the relation $x \sim y \iff x-y \in B$ I can understand $\frac{A}{B}$ better.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to see this is to look at it with the perspective of the isomorphism theorem.  In general, if you have a ring homomorphism $\phi:R_1 \rightarrow R_2$, then $Im(\phi) \cong R_1/\ker(\phi)$.

Now, consider the ring homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{0\}$ defined as follows:

$$\phi(x) \mapsto 0$$

You can check that this is indeed a ring homomorphism (usually referred to as the 'trivial' homomorphism).  Now, $\ker(\phi) = \mathbb{R}$ and $Im(\phi) = \{0\}$.  Therefore, by the isomorphism theorem, we have:

$$\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{R} \cong \{0\}$$

Comment: The OP fails to understand the object $A/A$, so I am not sure he will understand the object $R_1/\ker\phi$ and the subsequent isomorphisms...!

Comment: Perhaps.  When I learned algebra, quotient rings were covered on the same couple pages as the isomorphism theorem.  Also the way I see it, the answers are not only for OP's immediate benefit, but also OP in the future and other users as well.

Comment: @KajHansen, I didn't know that the isomorphism theorem could be used to calculate the quotient ring, so using as $\phi $ the identity function a can show just as well that $\frac{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{R}}= R$.

Comment: Careful, $\phi$ isn't the identity homomorphism since $\phi(x) \neq x$.  But yeah, this is actually my preferred method for understanding quotient rings (when applicable).  I usually try to search for a homomorphism with the latter ring as its kernel and go from there.  This has the advantage of not having to think about residue classes mod some ideal: You have a classic ring to look at instead! :)